# bash script that reads a text file, stores the numbers within the file and then compare these numbers with a specific value defined by me

Tags: bash, text

I have a text file with the following information:

```
Filesystem Use%
/dev/sda1 44%
/dev/sda7 35%
/dev/sda3 2%
/dev/sda2 5%
/dev/sda5 47%
tmpfs 0%
```

Now, I want to make a batch file that reads this text file, store the numbers of the lines 2,3,4,5 e 6 into some variables and then compare these numbers  with a specific value set by me. The comparison would be something like this:

```
variable = 44
if variable > 90
```

then it presents a console message whith the all the line of the variable stored.

```
variabletwo =35
if variabletwo > 90
```

then it presents a console message whith the all the line of the variable stored.

and so on...

Can someone help me please?

Comment: The batch-file tag indicates a Windows file - is it a bash script you are after?

Answer (score 0):

`awk` will ignore the `%` when converting the field to a scalar, so you can just do:

```
awk 'NR > 1 && NR < 7 && $2 > 90' input-file
```

to print each line (restricted to lines 2 thru 6) in which the second field is greater than 90.  You probably want a better way to restrict the lines, though.  Possibly

```
awk '$1 ~ /^\/dev/ && $2 > 90' input-file
```

If you want to include more text, do something like:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^\/dev/ && $2 > 90 { print "$1 is over the limit: $2" }
```

Comment: There is any version in Windows Batch script?

Comment: I'm confused, when you said "yes" in response to "is it a bash script you are after?", did you mean to say "no"?  Or do you require two solutions?  Does windows not provide `awk`?

Answer (score 0):

A regular script in pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

THRESHOLD=20
FILE_TO_TEST="/your/inputfile/here"
{
    read
    while read DISK USED
    do
        [[ ${USED/'%'/} -gt ${THRESHOLD} ]] && echo "$DISK" "$USED"
    done
} < "$FILE_TO_TEST"
```